# Formatting SmartSheet cells for currency

Tags: smartsheet-api

```
Rails 6
SmartsheetGem
```

I have an application, that produces a SmartSheet, with some sales data. It's working fine, but the cells with currency, are not properly formatted. The code below, for instance, produces a row in the SmartSheets worksheet, but the numbers do not have a currency sign ($) and no thousands separator.

```
columns = sheet_obj[:result][:columns]
location_col_id = columns[0][:id]
location_phone_col_id = columns[1][:id]
quarterly_sales_col_id = columns[2][:id]
yearly_sales_col_id = columns[3][:id]
cells = []
cells << {column_id: location_col_id, value: row[:location]}
cells << {column_id: location_phone_col_id, row[:phone]}
cells << {column_id: quarterly_sales_col_id, value: row[:q_sales]}
cells << {column_id: yearly_sales_col_id, value: row[:y_sales]}

body = {
    to_bottom: true,
    cells: cells,
    locked: false
}
```

I tried changing the body structure, to the following:

```
body = {
    to_bottom: true,
    cells: cells,
    locked: false,
    currency: [
        {code: "USD", symbol: "$"}
    ],
    decimalCount: [0],
    thousandsSeparator: ["on"]
}
```

But I am getting an error message:

```
Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Unknown attribute "currency" found at line 1, column 770
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please see the "UPDATE" section I've added to my answer below. I'm seeing what appears to be a bug with the ability to set celll format via API, and have the Smartsheet UI actually reflect the format you've specified.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Smartsheet API documentation, seems like you can specify the format of a cell  by setting the `cell.format` property for the cell. According the [formatting](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#formatting) section of the API docs, you'd set the value of `cell.format` to the following string value to achieve the formatting you've described (USD currency, with no decimals, and with thousands separator on):

`",,,,,,,,,,,13,0,1,2,,"`

I'm not familiar with the Ruby SDK, but I'd suspect that to implement this approach you'd simply add the format property to each currency cell that you're populating. For example:

`cells << {column_id: quarterly_sales_col_id, value: row[:q_sales], format: ",,,,,,,,,,,13,0,1,2,,"}`

**UPDATE**

I've been testing this a bit (via Postman) and seems like there may be a bug with being able to set cell format via API, and have it actually be reflected via the Smartsheet UI.

First, I submit an ADD ROW request to add a row to my sheet, setting the format of the cell value to specify USD currency, with 0 decimal places, and with thousands separator:

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5831916227192708/rows 
[
    {
        "cells": [
            {"columnId": 5759649950525316,"value": "1234", "format": ",,,,,,,,,,,13,0,1,2,,"}
        ]
    }
]
```

When the request is successful, I refresh my sheet via the Smartsheet UI -- but instead of seeing the cell value formatted as my request specified (`$1,234`), I see this:

[image: cell in Smartsheet]

So I then submit a GET SHEET request, to verify that the `format` property of that cell is set properly:

`GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5831916227192708?include=format`

In the response, the cell object I'm interested in looks like this:

```
{
    "columnId": 5759649950525316,
    "value": "1234",
    "displayValue": "1234",
    "format": ",,,,,,,,,,,13,0,1,2,,"
}
```

Interestingly, the `format` property is set correctly (specifying USD currency, with 0 decimal places, and with the thousands separator) -- BUT the `displayValue` property is set to `1234`, which is presumably what's determining how the cell value is appearing in the Smartsheet UI itself.

I'm unable to find a way via API to make the cell value that appears in the Smartsheet UI accurately reflect the currency format that's specified for that cell. However, if when viewing that sheet in the Smartsheet UI, I change the value in that cell (for example, to `5678`) and then press ENTER, the cell value DOES then accurately reflect the format that's present for that cell:

[image: another Smartsheet cell]

Seems like a bug to me, that the formatting of cell values set via the API are not being accurately represented in the Smartsheet UI (until if/when you update cell values via the UI). I'd be interested to know if you're able to find a way to make this work via API (else, perhaps someone from Smartsheet can chime in here to explain this behavior).

Comment: I really appreciate the effort. I saw this very example on their support site, but I could not understand it. Surely, there must be a better way to format, than ",,,,,,,,,,,13,0,1,2,,"?

Comment: Totally agreed -- that approach for specifying format isn't at all intuitive.

Comment: I resorted to formatting it in Ruby and then passing it as a string to the SmartSheet API

Comment: Fair enough! I'd suggest that you nonetheless specify the `format`property for each currency cell in your API request -- doing so will make it so that if/when anyone ever manually edits those cell values via the Smartsheet UI, the new values they enter will automatically reflect the proper (currency) format. Just a thought.